# C# create combobox to insert value into mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

can someone help a C# noob out here, i cant find anything online that shows how to do this. I am basically looking for a way to produce this html example in C#

```
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

i need it to have a text representation and a value for insert as seen above. I have searched high and low and all i seem to find are examples on how to populate a combobox from the results already in the table, not how to have some predefined results that are available to be inserted into the table.

Comment: As in ASP.NET or a WinForm?

Comment: You apparently didn't search very well. Here are a few keywords : databinding , datasource, DropDownList (ASP.NET)

Comment: in c# man, looking for it for a winform... i checked out databinding but that is not what im looking for, i want the items in the dropdown to be hardcoded into the windows form, not produced dynamically from a data source. I am a php programmer mainly so i am new to c# and winforms

Comment: `i cant find anything online that shows how to do this`. It doesn't look like you're trying to solve P = NP right here.

Comment: Yeah well done cabbage!! I have to say the arrogant people on here sometimes really drag this site down, I am well versed in programming, i am here looking for help with an issue that is totally new to me and in a totally new language.. ergo i have done as much research possible on comboboxs and have gotten as much info from google as i could in such a way that makes sense to me but alas i still cant solve my problem, so please spare me, if you havent got anything helpfull to say, say nothing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement with this example:

```
  public partial class TestForm1 : TestForm
    {
        public TestForm1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("value1","text1"));

            foreach (object o1 in comboBox1.Items)
            {
                if (o1 is ComboBoxItem)
                    MessageBox.Show("value=" + ((ComboBoxItem)o1).Value + "; text=" + ((ComboBoxItem)o1).Text);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public string Value;
        public string Text;
        public ComboBoxItem(string val, string text)
        {
            Value = val;
            Text = text;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
```

***And you can use the “ComboBoxItem” class as the data source’s items’s type.***

**For more information refer the links shared below:**

- [Stackoverflow link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085090/setting-both-text-and-value-to-combobox-items-in-wfa)
- [Stackoverflow link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046214/windows-forms-combobox-databind-to-multiple-properties)

Comment: Thanks for the response vishal, I have implemented something similar to this before but to no avail, i tried your example above also and it did not work but i can see it is on the right track to what i am looking for.

Comment: @user3461985- Try with the links i shared,specially the second one as first one is similar to what i answered.